# I can't search inside a text field for data with a hypen character

Tags: mysql

This query return nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE inks = "4 / 0 - [CMYK]"
```

But this one:

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE inks = "4 / 0 " + CHAR(150) + " [CMYK]"
```

or this one:

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE inks LIKE "4 / 0 % [CMYK]"
```

returns hundred of records. No matter if I use single or double quotes.

Why? I spend hours making different test but I can't get a reasonable explication.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using the wrong hyphen character in your first example.

For example, there's a difference between `—` (150 in Windows-1252) and `–` (151).

It could also be that your input data is UTF-8 encoded, in which case the hyphens wouldn't match either.

Comment: Table is utf-8 default collation, engine InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE inks LIKE "%-%";
```

It does not answer the why but the how ^^

Comment: This query works, so the problem is not with the hypen. The hypen I write with the keyboard it's the right one.